# Rails 3 tags for icon and Meta

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

can i just use  my

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/logo.ico" />
```

and meta tags in Ruby or is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use hand-written tags. It is the easiest way I know of.

Comment: i know in the public directory thers a favicon that was the reason i asked